# How to export SQL Server 2005 rows to excel? Everytime I do it I get errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, export-to-excel

I have SQL Server 2005 and I am trying to export a table into an Excel file.

I right click on my database and click export. I go through the wizard and choose to export to excel then I choose my one table that I want to export and hit finished.

I get this

> Messages
>
> - Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code
>     DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x00040EDA.
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task:
>     SSIS Error Code
>     DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. 
>     The "input "Destination Input" (72)"
>     failed because error code 0xC020907B
>     occurred, and the error row
>     disposition on "input "Destination
>     Input" (72)" specifies failure on
>     error. An error occurred on the
>     specified object of the specified
>     component.  There may be error
>     messages posted before this with more
>     information about the failure.     (SQL
>     Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task: SSIS
>     Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. 
>     The ProcessInput method on component
>     "Destination - SchoolUsers" (61)
>     failed with error code 0xC0209029. The
>     identified component returned an error
>     from the ProcessInput method. The
>     error is specific to the component,
>     but the error is fatal and will cause
>     the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>     There may be error messages posted
>     before this with more information
>     about the failure. (SQL Server
>     Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0047021: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error
>     Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread
>     "WorkThread0" has exited with error
>     code 0xC0209029.  There may be error
>     messages posted before this with more
>     information on why the thread has
>     exited. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

It seems to export one row and then it dies. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would export to csv, and then open that csv in Excel. Works for me. Whenever I tried to move data directly between Excel and SQL Server 2005 via wizards and SSIS, I was frequently encountering bugs. I don't do it anymore.

Comment: +1 those sql2005 wizards can be pretty buggy. Sometimes I've found the only way a text data import would work was to first import it into Access, then import that into SQL!

Comment: The sad thing is the wizards worked really well in 2000 much better than the 2005 and 2008 versions. I've learned on doing quick imports using the wizard (to see what the file is like before writing a real SSIS package with cleaning and all) to always go in and change the field size, what idiot thought 50 was a good standard?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, these kinds of issues are almost always related to data type conversion. Click on the "Edit Mappings..." button on the page where you select your source table and review the datatypes for the destination columns.

Comment: The 2 columns that I want are set a longtext. I changed them to varchar(..) but I still got the same errors.

Comment: I know Excel 2003 & 2007 limit a cell to 32,767 characters. Not sure about 2010. Is one of your columns exceeding that limit?

Comment: Did you try using a conversion step in the SSIS?

Comment: no the columns are 20 and 100 characters long. @Sam I am not sure what "SSIS" is

Comment: SSIS Assumes all Excel data will be nvarchar, you may need to conver to that. And there are issues if you are on a 64 bit machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2003 - 2007 has a limit of 32767 characters as mentioned by Joe. I suggest to check the length of your data in your suspicious column using this command

select * from yourtable 
where len(yourcolumn) > 32767

You will get the list of all rows in which the length exceeds the required limit. Remove these rows from this table and then try to export. It should work fine.